# Can someone with more rep than me create a tag for Bloodborne?

Tags: support, tags

I searched through the tag list for "Blood" and none of the results were for Bloodborne. I even searched through the new tags page as the game came out yesterday the 24th but I couldn't find a tag for this game. Could someone add it for me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask a question. Tag it PS4 or whatever and flag it for a mod to fix it. (Or don't even do that last part, now that this thread exists.)
Tags can only be created when there's a question to put them on.

Comment: +1 Just make sure you either include the name of the game somewhere else in the post or include it as a comment. that way A) any non-mod can fix it too B) Doesn't get closed as unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 2):

If you ask a question about it and can't yet create tags yourself, someone can create the tag for you on the question if you let us know it needs it. Otherwise, it will have to wait until someone asks a question about the game - tags are only created when they are used on a question.